# Self Sizing Cells do not work with Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've making a simple UITableViewCell prototype in a storyboard, but I'm having some issues with the self-sizing aspect. As you can see in the image below, the cell size increases, but the text doesn't move down. (It has 0 lines.) Here's the table's view controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let events = ["Kaufman Family Finished Project Reception", "Home Remodelers' Survival Guide", "Mori Family Mid-Construction Showcase"]
    let locations = ["La Cañada Flintridge", "Claremont", "Claremont"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell") as EventTableViewCell

        cell.eventName.text = events[indexPath.row]
        cell.eventLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Obviously I can't provide you with dozens of screenshots of the storyboard, so comment if you need other information. Here's some basic pictures though.
[image: Prototype Cell]
[image: Constraints]
[image: Incorrect Cell]
[image: Updated]

Comment: It doesn't look like (from your image) that you have a constraint between the two labels. Do you?

Comment: @rdelmar I do, it's pretty small though.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the constraint diagram... for this arrangement to work you need:

- Event Name label set to 0 lines (you said you do)
- Event Name label set to word wrap (by default it isn't)
- Event Name label constrained to top of cell and leading/trailing edges of cell
- Event Name label bottom constrained to top of Event Location label
- Same conditions for Event Location label - word wrap, 0 lines, if you want it to have variable number of lines
- Event Location label constrained to bottom of cell and leading/trailing edges of cell

This should allow both labels to dynamically size their height and for the cell to size itself to accommodate the label heights and margins.

One last thing... you are calling `sizeToFit` on the label after setting the text, right?

Here are some images from a project of mine where resizing labels work:

Final result:

[image: Final result]

"Questions Here" is the label being changed.

[image: "Questions Here" is the label being changed]

Size Inspector

[image: Size Inspector]

Properties Inspector

[image: Properties Inspector]

Comment: All of this was true except for word wrap - it stopped the truncation from occurring, but now it doesn't show the rest of the phrase. I'll add a new picture above.

Comment: Have you tried adding a pinned width constraint to the label? That's about my final suggestion, I have had this working recently.

Comment: Let me look into that later and get back to you tomorrow, I'm fairly new to storyboards in general.

Comment: I suspect it's "sizeToFit" you're missing

Comment: Just added sizeToFit on the cell, still nothing. Here's [the git](https://github.com/ZapChance/EventsTest).